# How to make my footer cover 100% height and width of the page from top?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an html page with header, footer and content. When user clicks on my footer, I want the footer to cover the whole page starting from the top. When i set the height and width of footer to be 100vh and 100vw. It makes it from the bottom. How do i make it cover from the top ?
[image: Image of the web page layout]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `percentage %` instead of `vh/vw/px`. You need to set `top:0;` and `height: 100%` (Full Height of device screen).

```js
function toggle() {

  var className = document.getElementById('footer').className;

  if (className == 'footer') {
  
    document.getElementById('footer').innerText = 'Click to minimize';
    document.getElementById('footer').className = 'footer full';
  
  } else {
  
    document.getElementById('footer').innerText = 'Click to miximize';
    document.getElementById('footer').className = 'footer';
  
  }


}
```

```css
.footer {

  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  
}

.full {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<h1>My heading</h1>

<p>

  Hello, this click on the footer to expand it.

</p>

<br>

<p>

  Hello, this click on the footer to expand it.

</p>

<br>

<p>

  Hello, this click on the footer to expand it.

</p>

<br>

<p>

  Hello, this click on the footer to expand it.

</p>

<br>

<p>

  Hello, this click on the footer to expand it.

</p>

<br>

<p>

  Hello, this click on the footer to expand it.

</p>

<br>

<p>

  Hello, this click on the footer to expand it.

</p>

<br>

<p>

  Hello, this click on the footer to expand it.

</p>

<br>

<p>

  Hello, this click on the footer to expand it.

</p>

<br>
<p>

  Hello, this click on the footer to expand it.

</p>

<br>

<div id='footer' class='footer' onClick='toggle()'>
  Click to maximise
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this for mine but it still only gets increased from the bottom and the top remains the same size

Comment: You should set `position: fixed;top:0`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.footer').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('new_footer');
    });



.new_footer{
    background-color: #000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;'
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  My heaader
</header>

<div>content</div>

<div class="footer">
 My footer
</div>
```